# How to specify name of mbean with annotation @MBean

Tags: java, jmx, apache-tomee, mbeans

I have SAR archive for JBoss and there is one MBean registered in `jboss-service.xml`.
Now I want to migrate to TomEE and use standard `javax.management` annotation `@MBean`, but I can't find out how to specify name of it and it  creates with default name.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the name when registering the bean as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/tutorial/essential.html):

```
  MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(); 
  ObjectName name = new ObjectName("com.example.mbeans:type=Hello"); 
  Hello mbean = new Hello(); 
  mbs.registerMBean(mbean, name);
```

Comment: Thank you. I already know it. But there is way to register MBean only with annotation without any code and it works, but with default name.

Comment: You could create your own annotations to wrap this functionality, see here: http://actimem.com/java/jmx-annotations/

Answer (score 2):

TomEE doesnt support it yet (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1668) but DeltaSpike does and keeps the CDI integration: https://github.com/apache/deltaspike/blob/1572c07eb8d5f892308e1060a9fa1ccdbf18435e/deltaspike/core/api/src/main/java/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/jmx/MBean.java#L57